# The footer is behind the main content, I think it needs a clear:both, but where?

Tags: html, css

I think this needs a clear:both somewhere, but where?

The situation: the footer is sitting behind the main content div.

Right now the footer is near the bottom of the page only because of a minimum-height on the main-content div.

[Here's how its looking](http://www.maharose.com/pages?cache=false&preview_key=8054f6515b55a1efbaa27ef78a9aeddf)

Comment: Is it supposed to be a 404 page?

Comment: You're using a grid layout, why do you need to deal with floats / clears directly?

Comment: I see no reason to use floating in the first place.

Comment: Please don't ask link only questions. When you fix the problem, the question will become useless. Instead, include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work well removing

```css
.details {
    height: 54px;
}
```

Comment: That worked. Awesome!!! But why?

Comment: Because if you set a small `height`, the content will overflow and overlap following elements.